# I am unable to get the Ids from carbonfield association field types

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, meta-boxes

Hi i am trying to get the stored value of carbon association field but getting values in this below format , i am using this to get the values

```
$meal_featured_recipe_section_meta_data = get_post_meta($section_id, 'carbon_fields_compact_input', true);
```

How can i get the recipe id ? yes i can explode then get the end part but there should be a way to get the association items id.

Thanks in advance

```
Array
(
    [_crb_section_type] => featured_recipies
    [_crb_banner_image] => 
    [_crb_featured_recipes] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => featured_recipes
                    [_posts] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => post:recipe:15
                            [1] => post:recipe:17
                            [2] => post:recipe:19
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I am trying to get the ids of the asoociation items.